# Is it permissible to name someone Ahmed Wali?

Tags: naming

My name is Ahmed Weli and i am a muslim. recently someone said that my name is not right and i shouldn't be called Ahmed Weli because Weli is one of the names of allah, and said you should be called Abdi Weli instead of Ahmed Weli. So my question goes like this, is it permissible for me to be called Ahmed Weli? there is also this kid that i know called Abdi nasiib(which translates to slave of luck) is his name also wrong?